# How to rotate attached monitor to notebook of Sony's Z-series?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

Is it possible that Sony is selling a top of the line, hugely expensive computer that does not have the basic ability to rotate an attached monitor? Is it possible that the  Z-series simply can't do this?   The Windows control panel is missing the normal option for "rotation",  as is the Nvidia control panel for "orientation" ,  no additional  rotation software   works.  Sony sales says they do not know the answer to this.  Sony technical supports says that the problem lies with Nvidia,  Nvidia technical supports says the problem lies with Sony.

Any advice for a fix for this short of returning the computer would be greatly appreciated. Also wondering if this problem is common to computers running Windows 7?

Comment: added your comment into your question - please edit your question for any further updates or details

Answer (score 0):

A third party application might be of help. Assuming the ctrl arrow combo does not work something like [iRotate](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/irotate.shtm) might help work around the issue

Comment: no it doesnt.  no third party application works.  tried them all.  on three different Z-series computers!